# control pointers to structures and put it in a function?

Tags: c++

I have a data structure task, where I must put for each node a following, a previous and a data of type string.

```
struct node {
    string data;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
};
```

The problem is that I have to make a circular doubly linked list, which I have no problem creating as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string data;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* makeNode(string data)
{
    struct node* newnode = new node();
    newnode->prev = newnode;
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = newnode;
    return newnode;
}

void Print(struct node* head)
{
    cout << "node->prev: " << head->prev << endl;
    cout << "node->data: " << head->data << endl;
    cout << "node->next: " << head->next << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    struct node* head = makeNode("Juan");
    struct node* newnode = makeNode("Carlos");

    struct node* temp = head->next;
    newnode->next = head;
    head->next = newnode;
    newnode->prev = head->next;
    
    Print(head);
    head = newnode;
    Print(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

node->prev: 0x600000018240

node->data: Juan

node->next: 0x600000018270

node->prev: 0x600000018270

node->data: Carlos

node->next: 0x600000018240

where it is true that the 'next' of the last node is the address of the 'previous' of the first node.

but at the moment of putting it in a function, everything thunders as always in the functions I am not so skilled.

```
struct node* addEnd(struct node* head, string data)
{
    struct node* newnode = makeNode();
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newnode;
        return newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp = head->next;
        newnode->next = head;
        head->next = newnode;
        newnode->prev = head->next;
        return head;
    }
}
```

any blessed soul that can help me please :( I've been trying to get it to work for two weeks, but the most I've achieved is without using functions.

Comment: you don't use the `string data` argument in your function. Functions are the great coding simplifier. You should study them in a good c++ book.

Comment: so the function fails for using strings?I forgot that newnode = makeNode(data);

Comment: There are other issues too. Functions pass arguments by value. So when you change a pointer that was passed by value (head) you do not change the value of the pointer where the function is called. c++ has a handy thing called references when you want to change the value at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a few things. This is your code. It's longer than it needs to be, and it has problems.

The biggest problem: you don't give newnode -> data the passed in data.

```
struct node* addEnd(struct node* head, string data)
{
    struct node* newnode = makeNode();
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newnode;
        return newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp = head->next;
        newnode->next = head;
        head->next = newnode;
        newnode->prev = head->next;
        return head;
    }
}
```

So you'll want to start with this. Note that we're not program C, so you don't need to say `struct node`. This should work.

```
    node * newnode = makenode();
    newnode->data = data;
```

Let's also back up a bit. I'm going to rewrite your node a little.

```
struct node {
    string data;
    node * prev = nullptr;
    node * next = nullptr;
};
```

On a stylistic note: please consider whitespace around operators. You'll see I added them before the `*`. As you work with older programmers with old, tired eyes, they'll appreciate a little bit more readability.

Now, for the rest of it. This is C++, not C. Please use nullptr. You said this is a circular list. Which means head->prev is the tail of the list, so if we want, we can insert after the tail, or we can insert at the head. Note that you were doing weird things with the pointers.

```
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = newnode;
    }
    else {
        newnode->next = head;
        newnode->prev = head->prev;
        head->prev = newnode;
        newnode->prev->next = newnode;

        // Do this last step if you want to insert at the
        // front. Exclude this last step if you want to push
        // at the back.
        head = newnode;
    }

    return head;
```

Here's what I'm going to recommend you do... Write out on paper what you have. You just need a few boxes in a row. Head points to one of the middle boxes. That box points to next to the right and prev to the left. They all do that. The ones at the end circle around.

Now, plop in a new box and think about what has to happen to the pointers to make it work.

I literally do this when I get confused.

Comment: What happens with the pointers I already did and that's why it works. The problem is when I put it in a function. How do I go to the last node?

Comment: From what I've researched you should use something like this:   node * temp = head; while(temp->next != head) temp = temp->next;

Comment: @JuanCarlos If you maintain it as a circular list and check for nulls, then head->prev is the last item in the ring.